# Rails 5 - Nested attributes in form, params missing or empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am trying to create two associated objects from two different models but I am still getting the same error "***param is missing or the value is empty: repost***" I have tried to figure out why it fails for days but in vain. Any hint?

I have the Model repost

```
class Repost < ApplicationRecord

 has_many :recurrences, inverse_of: :repost
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :recurrences

 def self.create_repost (twit_id)
  twit = Twit.find_by_id(twit_id)
  Repost.find_or_create_by(link: twit.link) do |repost|
   repost.twit_id = twit.id
   repost.content = twit.content
   repost.image_url = twit.image_url
   repost.content_url = twit.content_url
   repost.click = 0
   repost.like = 0
   repost.retweet = 0
   repost.engagement = 0
   repost.number_of_publications = repost.publications.count
   repost.likes_sum = 0
   repost.retweets_sum = 0
   repost.engagement_sum = 0
   repost.recurrence = repost.recurrences.recurring
 end

end
```

and the model Recurrence

```
class Recurrence < ApplicationRecord

 serialize :recurring, Hash
 belongs_to :repost, inverse_of: :recurrences

 def self.set(repost_id, frequency)
  repost = Repost.find_by_id(repost_id)
  Recurrence.create do |recurrence|
   recurrence.repost_id = repost.id
   recurrence.recurring = frequency
   recurrence.start_time = recurrence.created_at
   recurrence.end_time = nil
  end
 end

 def recurring=(value)
  if RecurringSelect.is_valid_rule?(value)
   super(RecurringSelect.dirty_hash_to_rule(value).to_hash)
  else
   super(nil)
  end
 end

 def rule
  rule = IceCube::Rule.from_hash(self.recurring)
  rule
 end

 def schedule
  schedule = IceCube::Schedule.new(self.created_at)
  schedule.add_recurrence_rule(rule)
  schedule
 end

end
```

here is my Repost Controller

```
class RepostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_repost, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :get_likes]

  def index
    @repost = Repost.new
    if params[:filter_by]
      @reposts = Repost.filter(params[:filter_by], params[:min], params[:max], params[:start_at], params[:end_at])
    else
      @reposts = Repost.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @repost = Repost.new
  end

  def create
    @repost = Repost.create_repost(repost_params)
    redirect_to reposts_path
  end

  def destroy
    @repost.destroy
    redirect_to reposts_path
  end


  private

  def find_repost
    @repost = Repost.find(params[:id])
  end

  def repost_params
    params.require(:repost).permit(:twit_id, recurrences_attributes: [:recurring])
  end

end
```

and here is my view with the form

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <h1 class="twit-h1">My best Tweets</h1>
      <p><%= render "filter_form" %></p>
      <p><% @twits.each do |twit| %></p>
        <p><%= form_for @repost do |f| %></p>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :twit_id , twit.id %>
        <div class="twit">
          <%= image_tag "#{twit.image_url}", class: "twit-image" %>
          <div class="twit-body">
            <% if twit.content.present? %>
              <h3><%= twit.content %></h3>
            <% else %>
              <%= "This tweet has no text" %>
            <% end %>
            <% if twit.content_url.present? %>
              <%= link_to "#{twit.content_url}".truncate(40), twit.content_url, class: "twit-link" %>
            <% else %>
              <%= "This tweet has no link" %>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.fields_for :recurrences do |r| %>
            <h6 style="float: right;"><%= r.select_recurring :recurring %></h6>
            <% end %>
            <h6>
              <i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa" aria-hidden="true"></i> <%= twit.engagement %>
              <i class="fa fa-retweet fa" aria-hidden="true"></i> <%= twit.retweet %>
              <i class="fa fa-heart fa" aria-hidden="true"></i> <%= twit.like %>
            </h6>
            <p>Tweeted on <%= (twit.first_date).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y at %I:%M%p %Z") %></p>
            <%= link_to "Delete", twit_path(twit), name: nil, class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm", method: :delete, data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'} %>
            <%= f.submit "Add to your Reposts library", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update, here is my logs

Started POST "/__better_errors/923b59f8da1318ef/variables" for ::1 at 2017-02-21 15:52:56 +0100
Started POST "/reposts" for ::1 at 2017-02-21 15:54:14 +0100
Processing by RepostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"62pE3le5m99HF10RgQcd70wFHqWQWiRmQQO2ndNHT3gnceRu94Y1ttyBuSExBjr4/cxeVUtgY60GRThxdpFGJg==", "twit_id"=>"1844", "recurring"=>"{\"interval\":1,\"until\":null,\"count\":null,\"validations\":{\"day\":[1],\"hour_of_day\":1,\"minute_of_hour\":0},\"rule_type\":\"IceCube::WeeklyRule\",\"week_start\":0}", "commit"=>"Add to your Reposts library"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: repost:

It seems my error comes from this private method in my Repost controller but I can't understand why?

```
def repost_params
 params.require(:repost).permit(:twit_id, recurrences_attributes: [:recurring])
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: are you calling that view within your 'new' action in your controller?

Comment: Can you post the params that get posted to the controller? They will be in the terminal where your rails server is running.

Comment: @RichardAE I've just updated my post with my logs !

Comment: @KcUS_unico I am calling the 'create' action

Comment: you should use  f.hidden_field_tag :twit_id, currently you are missing the F

Comment: I still get the same error from here `def repost_params
    params.require(:repost).permit(:twit_id, recurrences_attributes: [:recurring])
  end`

Comment: If you look at the params you don't have a 'repost' key at all which is why that error is being raised, you only have 'recurring'. Are you on rails 5? Can you use byebug or the console debugger and write this '@repost.class.name' and tell me what it says?

Comment: @RichardAE I am on Rails5 and '@repost.class.name' is 'NilClass'

Comment: When are you doing that? You use @repost to create the form so it can't be nil, make sure you are doing that command after @'repost has been set in the controller.